# Why does SQL support two single quotes as well as backslash escaping

Tags: sql, postgresql, security, escaping

I was recently surprised to discover that two single quotes is a valid way to escape a single quote (as an alternative to using a backslash) in Postgres and other SQL databases.  Some of the documentation I was reading in fact referred to that as the "normal" way to escape a single quote.

```
-- Using two single quotes
SELECT FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'o''keefe@email.com'

-- Using a backslash
SELECT FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'o\'keefe@email.com'
```

I was hoping someone could provide some context around the origins of that form of escaping, and any advantages or disadvantages it has relative to the backslash form.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks for the feedback.  Yes, the backticks were based on syntax read in other documentation. I've edited the question to reflect your corrections.

Comment: "SQL" does not support backslashes - that's an extension that Postgres supports and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

postgres supports various ways:

standard:

```
t=# select 'the quote is ''';
    ?column?
----------------
 the quote is '
(1 row)
```

backslash requires `E` to recognise  escape, look 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE

> PostgreSQL also accepts “escape” string constants, which are an
>   extension to the SQL standard. An escape string constant is specified
>   by writing the letter E (upper or lower case) just before the opening
>   single quote, e.g., E'foo'.

```
t=# select e'the quote is \'';
    ?column?
----------------
 the quote is '
(1 row)
```

and lastly most effective and totally non standard dollar quoting, look here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING

> While the standard syntax for specifying string constants is usually
>   convenient, it can be difficult to understand when the desired string
>   contains many single quotes or backslashes, since each of those must
>   be doubled. To allow more readable queries in such situations,
>   PostgreSQL provides another way, called “dollar quoting”, to write
>   string constants. A dollar-quoted string constant consists of a dollar
>   sign ($), an optional “tag” of zero or more characters, another dollar
>   sign, an arbitrary sequence of characters that makes up the string
>   content, a dollar sign, the same tag that began this dollar quote, and
>   a dollar sign.

```
t=# select $dollar_quotes$the quote is '$dollar_quotes$;
    ?column?
----------------
 the quote is '
(1 row)
```

Comment: postgresql will support backslash quoting without the `e` prefix,  if the setting `standard_conforming_strings` is turned off.

Comment: that depends how old your install is - off used to be the default.

Comment: yes, but 9.1 Is like 8 yeas old, since then they changed default. Frankly saying I had a gap with postgres and came back with 9.3, so for me last install without e for c like escape was like 15years ago. You think I should mention `standard_conforming_strings` in my answer, @Jasen?

Comment: I've mentioned it. that's probably enougn.

Answer (score 3):

The double single quotes is the ANSI standard way of putting a single quote in a string for SQL.

The backslash is a common convention, particularly on Unix-based machines, so many databases also support it.

I prefer the double single quotes because it is ANSI standard.  I also get confused with backslashes when going between Windows and Unix boxes.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.esqlc.doc/ids_esqlc_0015.htm) ANSI standards specify that using the backslash character `\` to escape single `'` or double `"` quotation marks is invalid. So I would go with the double single quotes for portability reasons.

Comment: I edited for readability - hope I did not ruin the sense here